# Link to a git repository from within a repository

Tags: git, version-control, symlink

I'm considering the following scenario. In directory `~/foo` I have a git repository which I shall call `main`. This repository is exposed and public, but it depends on codes that I store in two different directories `~/bar1` and `~/bar2`. These directories are tracked by two *different* git repositories `support1` and `support2`, respectively. Both `support`'s repositories are private and have to be kept private. For the sake of simplicity and order I would like to link to `support`s from within `main`. However, I do not want it to be reflected in the repository `main` itself and I want to keep all three repositories independent from each other.

The solution I have in mind is to create a directory `~/foo/support` in `main` and add it to `.gitignore`, so it won't be tracked. Then, in this new directory create two symbolic links to `~/bar1` and `~/bar2`.

Is there some hidden problem with this solution? Is there anything particular I should be careful about?